# SP Calculated Columns with nested IF statements

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I'm looking for some advice on nested IF statements within SP as what I am trying keeps giving me errors. I'm trying to get my statement correct and if I can't should I be using a flow instead of the calculated column.

I have a choice column [System Architecture] consisting of 6 choices, each choice has a review cycle added to it which converted into days will determine my next review due date. I can't seem to get this right.

So the choices are and what values I want them to return:

- A = 365 days
- B = 1460
- C = 730 days
- D = 1095 days
- E and F = 0 days

```
=IF(([System Architecture]="A","365"),IF([System Architecture]="B","1460"),IF([System Architecture]="C","730"),IF([System Architecture]="D","1095"),IF([System Architecture]="E","0"),IF([System Architecture]="F","0"))
```

I have managed to get one IF statement to work but as soon as I add my additional statements in, I only get syntax errors. Single working IF Statement:

```
=IF([System Architecture]="A","365")
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula for your calculated column:

```
=IF([System Architecture]="A","365",IF([System Architecture]="B","1460",IF([System Architecture]="C","730",IF([System Architecture]="D","1095",IF(OR([System Architecture]="E",[System Architecture]="F"),"0","")))))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: I tried that aswell and still didnt work. Thankyou for the help.

Comment: What is the error message? Make sure you are using correct display name of system architecture column and selecting return type of calculated column as "Single line of text" (this setting is available below text box where you add the formula).